# How to encode H3 geohash in regression model

Tags: random-forest, data-cleaning, encoding, geospatial

I'm trying to train a random forest regression model based on a number of features, including location. I know that [raw lat/long can't be used directly](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/can-gps-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-be-used-as-features-in-a-linear-mod), so I've bucketed them using [H3](https://eng.uber.com/h3/).

I'm struggling to figure out how to encode the hex grid IDs in the training data. The IDs are just 64bit integers, so can I just feed them directly into my model, or do I need to do another kind of encoding?